Roadmap for p-adic geometry
I think some questions asked in similar fashion with this one. I am a master student in mathematics. I have knowledge in algebraic geometry(both in Shafarevich's and Vakil's books), algebraic topology (most of the May's A concise course in algebraic topology), complex analysis (Gamelin's book) and algebra (Hungerford's book). I want to introduce myself to p-adic geometry. What is a good roadmap for my background. I haven't taken any number theory or representation theory course. What should I learn before going into the articles of Scholze or Bhatt? If you link some books or articles, I would much appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Scholze has given many courses/lectures on all aspects of his research. Probably it is better to learn from those than from the original research articles. For example, typing "scholze p-adic geometry" into Google immediately yields these "Berkeley lectures on p-adic geometry": https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/scholze-berkeley.pdf. Looks like those could be useful for you.

@SamHopkins Thank you very much for your answer. However, when I try to work on these notes, I experience some hardship. I mean, I mostly understand it but I do not know some parts of the proofs because I lack information about representation theory. I am curious that should I start working on these notes and look at the relevant references when needed or  cover some of the representation theory, number theory, etc. and then dive into these notes?

Sorry, I am not an algebraic geometer and no nothing of this subject. Just wanted to point out to you that there are resources online. I hope others can offer more guidance. But also, obviously the best person to give you specific advice of this kind would be your masters advisor.

Bosch’s book “Lectures on Formal and Rigid Geometry” is a good start. And Kedlaya’s lectures in the AWS volume on perfectoid spaces.
